# Path dependency of template

Tags: errors, templates, input, include, paths

I created a template (`myclass.cls`), which includes another file (`mystyle.sty`) using the input command. Then I used the template in a document (`mydocument.tex`). The directories are as follow:

```
mypath/myclass.cls
mypath/mystyle.sty
mypath/project/mydocument.tex
```

The template file

```
\newcommand{\classname}{myclass}
\providecommand{\baseclass}{article}
\LoadClass{\baseclass}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{\classname}

\input{mystyle.sty}

...

\endinput
```

The document file

```
\documentclass{../myclass}

\begin{document}

...

\end{document}
```

The document file will not compile because, while `mystyle.sty` exists relative to `myclass.cls`, it does not exist relative to `project/mydocument.tex`, such that when I compile `project/mydocument.tex`, I receive the error that `mystyle.sty` cannot be found.

I have seen solutions like defining some path variables, but I am inquiring the possibility of making the path of `mystyle.sty` relative to `myclass.cls` (the location of the template) not `document.tex` (the location of the file that uses the template).

Comment: the argument to `\documentclass` should be a name not a path so `\documentclass{myclass}` input paths are always relative to the directory from which you run tex, not the directory of any file.

Comment: Thanks David! Unfortunately, the template file would not be found if I use ```myclass``` instead of ```../myclass```, as the template file is in the parent directory.

Comment: No that is the same issue (and why latex warns you on the ProvidesClass that you have used the wrong name). Put the .cls and the.sty in a directory in your tex input path (usually `~/texmf/tex/latex` would work in texlive at least) and then you can just use the names in both cases.

Comment: you could of course use `\input{../mystyle.sty}` and it would work but it is wrong and makes the document non-portable and latex will warn you about the mis-use of `../myclass` as the class name.